# how to filter the associated security groups of an ec2 instance using terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-security-group

I am trying to get the security groups associated with the instance with id "i-0abcdefgh1234" but the output gives no result.

## terraform.tf

```
data "aws_instance" "ec2" {
     instance_id = "i-0abcdefgh1234"

     filter {
        name = "tag:Name"
        values = ["name-of-the-server"]
      }
    }

    output "sg" {
       value = "${data.aws_instance.ec2.*.security_groups}"
    }
```

## Output

```
data.aws_instance.ec2: Refreshing state...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.
```

Tried with and without * below

```
value = "${data.aws_instance.ec2.*.security_groups}"
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: specifying an instance ID and other filters is redundant as the instance ID is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The interpolation syntax for data sources is `data.TYPE.NAME.ATTRIBUTE`. See [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-a-data-source)

In your case it will be `${data.aws_instance.ec2.security_groups}`

However, as the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html#attributes-reference) states - "Some values are not always set and may not be available for interpolation."